# How to get #entries of last hour in MySQL, correcting for timezone?

Tags: mysql, timezone, gmt

I am storing activity entries in a MySQL table. The table has a date_created field of type timestamp and through PHP I insert the activity entries based on GMT:

```
$timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

This works fine. On my client I am on GMT+2. If it is 16:00 here and I insert an entry, it is stored in MySQL as 14:00. This is as expected I guess. My

Now I would like to get the number of activity entries from MySQL within the last hour. I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM karmalog WHERE user_id = ' 89' AND event='IMG_UPD' 
AND date_created > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

This returns nothing, because CURRENT_TIMESTAMP uses the MySQL timezone settings, which is set to SYSTEM, which is set to GMT+2. I guess what I am looking for is a GMT_CURRENTTIMESTAMP in MySQL, is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) function, which returns the current UTC timestamp in a contextually-sensitive manner.  You can use that in place of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM karmalog WHERE user_id = ' 89' AND event='IMG_UPD' 
AND date_created > DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I was not aware that UTC and GMT are the same thing, timezone-wise. I guess I was searching for the wrong term.